# how to send data from one database to another using linked server

Tags: sql-server

I have created a linked server to copy data from one database to another and this worked well when I manually write the query and execute it. But I want this to be scheduled to happen automatically. Should I use linked server for this or is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: lookup: Sql server agent job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQL scripts to transfer data, you can use SQL Script job step in a new SQL Server job.
I've created a step by step short tutorial showing how to [create SQL Server job](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/create-sql-server-job-for-periodic-tasks.aspx) which executes a SQL stored procedure periodically according to the assigned execution schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the scheduled jobs, with SQL Server Agent.

In short, you will need to created a stored procedure that executes the moving code you need.
Then, from Databases > SQL Server Agent > Jobs, you can create a new scheduled job to make it run when you need it to.